# Linked list data unreadable/gone after calling printf

Tags: c

I'm doing a chess board path explorer. I print a menu for the users and they picks which option they want to use. Loads of these functions depend on other ones and it will be very long to copy
everything here so will show where the problem occurs.

I'm creating a trie getting all the possible paths of a chess Knight. I use this tree to find if there's a path that covers all the chessboard cells and return a linked list of this path. If it exists I want to ask the user for a name for a new binary file I'll proceed to create containing this path that covers all the board.

I tested this a lot and eventually after I finish running the function to get the linked list of the path perfectly, I return to the menu function and there when I first encounter a `printf` command then the linked list data is unreadable from then on according to my debugger on Visual Studio.
Any ideas as to why this could happen?

Main outline of the project code:

```
void sectionOperator()
{
    int option = 0;
    char row, col;
    char* file;
    int flag = TRUE;
    chessPos kPos;  kPos[0] = 0; kPos[1] = 0;
    pathTree pathT;     pathT.root = NULL;
    chessPosList* posList = NULL; 

    printMenu();

    while (option != 4)
    {
        option = receiveOptionFromUser();

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            while (flag)
            {
                printf("Please enter a position on the board, a char for the row (A - H) and a number for the col (1 - 8):\n");
                scanf(" %c%c", &row, &col);

                if ('A' <= row && row <= 'H' && '1' <= col && col <= '8')
                    flag = FALSE;
            }

            kPos[0] = row;
            kPos[1] = col;
            break;

        case 2:
            if (kPos[0] == 0 && kPos[1] == 0)
                printf("Please enter first a knight's starting position (option 1)");
            else
            {
                pathT = findAllPossibleKnightPaths(kPos);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            if (kPos[0] == 0 && kPos[1] == 0)
                printf("Please enter first a knight's starting position (option 1)\n");

            else
            {
                if (pathT.root == NULL)
                    pathT = findAllPossibleKnightPaths(kPos);

                // Gets the linked list of the path.
                posList =  findKnightPathCoveringAllBoard(&pathT);

                if (posList == NULL)
                   break;

                // posList data unreadable after this printf
                printf("Please enter file name:\n");

                scanf("%s", file);
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        default:
            printf("Enter an option from the list above\n");
        }

    }
    printf("Exiting\n");
}

// Here is the function that finds the path and creates linked list. Too long to copy every function it calls but I assure you the list is giving expected when this finished running. 
chessPosList* findKnightPathCoveringAllBoard(pathTree *path_tree)
{
    chessPosList lst;
    chessPosArray* visited;

    createEmptyList(&lst);
    visited = (chessPosArray*)malloc(sizeof(chessPosArray));
    checkMemoryFail(visited);
    visited->size = 0;

    if (findPathRec(path_tree->root,visited))
    {
        createPathList(&lst,visited);
        return &lst;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}


/* Prints the main menu */
void printMenu()
{
    printf("1. Enter a knight's starting position\n");
    printf("2. Create all possible knight paths\n");
    printf("3. Find a knight path covering all board and save to file\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
}

/* Receives an option from the user */
int receiveOptionFromUser()
{
    int option;

    printf("Please enter the number of your option\n");

    scanf("%d", &option);

    return option;
}
```

Comment: If possible, please provide a [mre], which includes everything needed to compile the example, including a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: In `findKnightPathCoveringAllBoard` you are returning a pointer to a local variable at `return &lst;`

Comment: regarding:  `if ('A' <= row && row <= 'H' && '1' <= col && col <= '8')
                    flag = FALSE;`   This says that both the user entered ROW AND the user entered COL must be wrong before `flag` is set true.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest: `if (  ('A' <= row && row <= 'H'  )||  ('1' <= col && col <= '8') )
                    flag = FALSE;`  <== note the 'or' and the parens for grouping

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", file);`  1) when using the `%s` input format conversion specifier, always include a MAX WIDTH characters modifier that is 1 less than the width of the input buffer because this specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior  2) when calling any of the scanf() family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  For this specific statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
if (findPathRec(path_tree->root,visited))
{
    createPathList(&lst,visited);
    return &lst;
```

The variable `lst` is a local variable  (I.E. on the stack),  Any local variable goes 'out of scope' when the enclosing function exits (and will be overwritten by anything that uses the stack (like `printf()`(